# Why wouldn't Hugo show Josef his silver stake?

Tags: undead-girl-murder-farce

At 20:18 of episode 3 of Undead Murder Farce, Aya interrogates a man about Hugo, a hunter that tried to kill the vampire Lord Goddard.

> **Aya**: By the way, Josef, did you know that Hugo had a silver stake?
>
> **Josef**: Silver?
>
> **Aya**: You didn't know it was silver?
>
> **Josef**: Well, he always kept it in a leather case. No wonder he never showed it to me, even when I asked.

Traditionally silver stakes can be used to kill vampires. Hugo had already told Josef about his plans to kill the vampire Lord Goddard, so why wouldn't Hugo want to show Josef about his silver stake?

Comment: I'm guessing that the next episode will provide an answer to this, having not read the source material myself.